# Using a multiline textbox as query criteria to fill a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, loops, datagridview

This is my second question here in StackOverflow and this is where im stuck

i want to loop every value in a multiline textbox and pass it as query criteria then fill my DataGridView with the result (multiple results).

The problem is. that i cannot pass more than 1 value from the textbox. i can execute correctly the query but its not looping correctly as it only shows the result of the first value in my data grid and i want the data(result) from every line in the textbox

my code is

```
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Connect();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd = new OracleCommand(OraSql + OraSql2 + orasql3 + OraSql4, con);
            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add
                    (
                        row[0].ToString(),
                        row[1].ToString(),
                        row[2].ToString(),
                        row[3].ToString(),
                        row[4].ToString(),
                        row[5].ToString()
                    );

            }


        }
```

i hope that i explained myself correctly here
Thank you!

this is my query

```
            string OraSql = @"SELECT   r.ixkitl ""Parent Part Number"",
         r.ixlitm ""Component Part Number"",
         i.imdsc1 ""Description"",
         SUM((r.ixqnty/10000)) ""Qty per Harness"",
         To_date(r.ixefff+1900000, 'YYYYDDD') ""Effective From Date"",
         To_date(r.ixefft+1900000, 'YYYYDDD') ""Effective Thru Date"",
         r.ixtbm ""Bill Type"",
         r.ixmmcu ""Branch Plt""
FROM     proddta.f3002 r,
         proddta.f4101 i";

            string OraSql2 = @"
WHERE    (i.imlitm IN '" + textBoxX1.Text.ToString() + "'AND      i.imitm = r.ixkit)";
            string orasql3 = @"
            AND      (r.ixmmcu = '        3320' AND      r.ixtbm = 'M  ')";

            string OraSql4 = @"
AND      r.ixefff <= (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYYDDD')-1900000)
AND      r.ixefft >= (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYYDDD')-1900000)
GROUP BY r.ixkitl,
         r.ixlitm,
         r.ixqnty,
         r.ixtbm,
         r.ixmmcu,
         r.ixefff,
         r.ixefft,
         i.imdsc1
ORDER BY r.ixkitl,
         r.ixlitm";
```

Comment: What is the sql you are attempting to execute?

Comment: Sorry. just added the Query to the post

Comment: I suggest changing your approach.  When looping through the lines, create a list query parameters.  Then run a single query which includes `and i.imitm in (parameters go here)`.   Not related to your question, but this looks wrong:  `(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYYDDD')-1900000)
`.  to_char returns a string so you shouldn't attempt math with it.

Comment: im using that to convert Julian date to Gregorian date
sorry if i cannot be more specific because its a premade query that i have to use

Comment: Your premade query that you have to use has a problem.  This, `WHERE    (i.imlitm IN '" + textBoxX1.Text.ToString() + "'AND      i.imitm = r.ixkit)";
`.  is running inside your loop.  However, each time through the loop this, `textBoxX1.Text.ToString() ` has the same value.